# Earplugs hacks for keeping water out of my ears?

Tags: water, sports

My ears start to ache after swimming 4-6 laps of my daily workout, and it's getting really annoying. I thought I would ask for a solution here before I consider buying from a sporting goods store... Any ideas???

If anyone thinks that one of the posts about earplugs for going to sleep in a noisy room is a good fit for this then please feel free to link to it. otherwise, I do not consider this to be a repeat, as I am asking for a completely different reason.

Comment: When you get to ache doing otherwise ordinary tasks, like swimming, you should seriously consider contacting a doctor/your GP.  You might have an illness causing your ache, and just to bypass the symptoms using a hack could be potential dangerous.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't being clear. the ache is from water in my ears. If I wait a minute in between laps, and tip my head to the side or pop my ears, it goes away. It fades away within seconds of leaving the pool. I know what this is. I'm not in danger

Answer (score 1):

Swimmers wax. My young nephew is prone to ear infections and had tubes in his ear. Both to go to the pool and to take a bath, he uses this product. It's not a hack, but it is typically under $2 from a drugstore, so I'd call it close enough. Basically any paraffin/wax that is mold-able, but not soft enough to "drip" or ooze into your ear canal.

Comment: Wax earplugs available too for preventing water ingress